# Background process's redirected output not showing in the file

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, expect, sh

I'm having problems with redirecting my command's output to a file, when I invoke the command as a background process.

> spawner.sh user@host ". ./.profile >> /dev/null 2>&1;runjobs
>   SOMEJOB" > test.log &

spawner.sh script uses #!/usr/local/bin/expect interpreter and it spawns a new process (SOMEJOB) on a remote host and interacts with it. When I remove ampersand on the end of this statement, output is being written to the test.log file. But when I run this in the background (with the ampersand), my log file is empty.

Any ideas guys and girls?

Comment: Does it not appear even after the script finishes? I can imagine running in background to have effect on buffering.

Comment: It does not finish :D. That's why I need output to be written to file. I'm parsing the output so I can see when all useful work is done, so I can kill that process. My main script does not continue until I kill this child process. I have no alternative to this, I must do it this way. Don't ask :D

Comment: Is the expect process run locally, or remotely?

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem with a python script and it turned out to be the buffering within python.
Using the -u option as in *python **-u** < /dev/null >> file 2>&1 &* solved my case.

Other script languages might have a similar option as *python -u*

Answer (score 0):

try turning off stdout buffering in the expect script.

```
fconfigure stdout -buffering none
```